# Where is browserNoActivityTimeout used in karma?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I grep the [karma repository](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=browserNoActivityTimeout&type=) and it seems like no logic is using that field besides simply being set in the config.

Does anyone know what is that field for?

For some reason I have to set it to `20000` or else my karma test `Disconnects`

Answer (score 3):

It's referenced as `noActivityTimeout` internally, in this file:
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/de55bc63205c656eb5f5534894aa4ae92228efb8/lib/browser.js

Basically, the effect of the line is supposed to be that the test stops running if no activity is detected in the amount of time specified by the config. This helps the tests stop when your code is in an infinite loop or otherwise not responding (maybe it has an async test condition and the test never resolves)

Comment: is there preprocessing somewhere compiling  `/* config.browserNoActivityTimeout */ noActivityTimeout`  such that it assigns `noActivityTimeout` to reference to `browserNoActivityTimeout` I thought that was just a comment. Also I don' think I have infinite loop since increasing timeout resolves my issue.